# Do a check if input value contains house number and possible extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if an input value contains a house number and a possible extension before it is accepted for input. The entire input is received as a string (even the numbers).

```
jQuery('#billing_address_1').attr('value');
```

The input for this should be checked for something like: myaddress 123 9bis. 9bis is a possible address extension that a customer could fill in. We don't need to do a check for the extension. House number is important. If no house number is present, we want to alert something.

At the moment, it is accepting any kind of input. Sometimes our customers forget to enter house number.

What's the best way to get this done?

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: First you need to specify your acceptance criteria. Specifically, define what constitutes a valid input. Unit testing will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use regex like so:

```
function containsInt(myString) {
  return /\d/.test(myString);
}
```

> The test() method tests for a match in a string. - w3schools.com

more info about [js test()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)
working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11n1hurm/)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use some sort of validation which checks whether the address matches an address format I.e number followed by a word.

I created a basic example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08eLe33x/ which splits the string into an array and checks it matches a basic address pattern.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
    // validate address
    var data = $("input").val().split(" ");
    if (isNaN(data[0])===false) {
        if (data[1] !== undefined) {
         alert("Valid address");
      } else {
        alert("Invalid address");
      }
    } else {
        alert("Invalid address");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Fails if street number ends with a letter. E.g "221B Baker St."